# Unit testing ext js with Jasmine 2.0 and PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, extjs, jasmine, phantomjs

I'm trying to setup unit testing for my ext js application. 
I'm using Jasmine 2.0 and PhantomJS to run  the tests from console. 
I can successfully init the store in the init method of the controller.
But, if I try to declare it in the stores config, I'm getting the following error :
TypeError: 'null' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new c()') (line 1) (1) ,
What is the cause for the error,  and how can it be resolved?

Thank you in advance.

My code is below:

TestApplication.js

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true });
Ext.ns('myApp');

// Loading different components like controller, model, view..
Ext.application({
    name: 'myApp',
    appFolder: '../App',
    controllers: [],
    autoCreateViewport: false,

    init : function() {
        myApp.app = this;
    },

    // Launch Jasmine test environment
    launch: function () {
        var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
        jasmineEnv.updateInterval = 1000;
        var htmlReporter = new jasmine.HtmlReporter();
        jasmineEnv.addReporter(htmlReporter);
        jasmineEnv.execute();
    }

});
```

spec.js

```
describe("myController", function () {
    var ctrl= null,
        store = null;

    beforeEach(function () {
        bmTab = Ext.create("myApp.controller.myController");
        bmTab.init();
    });
});
```

myController.js

```
Ext.define('myApp.controller.myController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    //stores: [Stores.myStore];

    init:function() {
        console.log('**** init');
        var store = Ext.create(Stores.myStore);

        console.log('**** store created' + store);
    }    
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `Stores.myStore` would be resolved properly at the time when the specified store is initialized, could you give it a try by specifying the value of `Stores.myStore` by hard coding it in `stores` config ?

Comment: @Cyclone 
Do you mean explicitly specifying the full namespace? 
I tried that. Same result

Comment: Hmm :-/
I'm wondering what else is going wrong...

Comment: And I hope this semicolon at the end of the statement `//stores: [Stores.myStore];` is typo, correct ? :) Coz it should be a comma.

Comment: @Cyclone, tried that with alias too. The error still shows.

Comment: @Cyclone yes. the semicolon is a typo.

Comment: @Cyclone hi, again. I'm sorry to bug you, but I have some new observations. Maybe you'll have some insight. I followed this article [link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/guide/testing) and modified my TestApplication.js to be initialized inside of Ext.onReady event and I put debugger; statements in the specs and inside Ext.onReady function. Now, It seems, that all of my specs run **before** the Ext.Ready event is fired.

Comment: I believe those test specs were executed before introducing `Ext.onReady`, then it may not be needed, as `launch` method does the same. I am not sure, but I'm suspecting something to be wrong with `loader`. try specifying [`paths`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.Loader-cfg-paths) config to loader with `paths: { 'myApp' : //relative path to the folder which contains store, controller, etc. }`. You might have to do some trial and error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was using **Jasmine 2.0**, when all of the tutorials were using **Jasmine 1.3**. 
In Jasmine 2.0 a file **boot.js** was introduced. 
And it was calling `jasmine.getEnv().execute()` on `window.onload`. 
Because of that, specs were executing before Ext.launch was called.
Once I removed the call to `execute()` from the boot.js it all started working.
Below is a final version of my TestApplication.js code

P.S.
Note that, HtmlReporter is also initialized in the boot.js, so there is no need to init it on the Ext.launch function

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true });

Ext.application({
    name: 'myApp',
    appFolder: '../App',
    controllers: [],
    autoCreateViewport: false,

    // Launch Jasmine test environment
    launch: function () {
        var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
        jasmineEnv.updateInterval = 1000;
        jasmineEnv.execute();
    }
});
```